# How can I detect any bad request from some external requests (as similar as firebug does) by .NET?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, pageload

Our web page will raise some external HttpRequest such as "fls.uk.doubleclick.net", how can I capture these requests and get their response StatusCode (just like firebug does)?

Comment: How exactly is you web page going to raise these `HttpRequest`s? What language? What platform?

Answer (score 1):

For what purpose? Generally speaking, you can't do this from JavaScript. You could use Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) or build your own debugger on FiddlerCore (http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need capture these response as these external connections break the page load performance when they have problem. I'm not going to use javascript. I prefer .NET code can help me achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) or [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to retrieve the web page and query the results - including the response headers and status codes.

Comment: @Oded, can you show me a bit code snippet for retrieving the response status from WebClient?

Comment: @Zalan - See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx

Comment: @Oded, all of the sample codes I found so far are creating the new instance first by URL. I'm actually looking for how to deal with existing HttpRequest raised from one page. I dont know what the URLs I'm going to deal with. The best example is I mentioned from my original question: firebug

Comment: @Zalan - firebug is _in the browser_, not in the server (as C# is).

Comment: @Oded, sorry for not expressing my question clearly, i think that might because I didnt get what I want to achieve at the beginning. Now I'm trying to ask my question again here: How can I detect any bad request from some external requests (as similar as firebug does) by .NET

Comment: @Zalan - it is better that you ask a _new_ question in that case.

Comment: @Oded, i've changed the question title